Did the brightness of the glory of God cause a physical change in the color of the hair of the Lord Jesus Christ?
I have been reading the Book of Revelation and it sounds as if the current color of the hair of Jesus is white as wool but the disciples of Jesus saw it in the resurrected body and it was in the same color he was crucified with.
Revelation 1:14

"His hair was white as white wool, white as snow"

Jesus was born with a regular hair like other Jews but it seems as if the glory of God caused that to change, did the spiritual brightness of God cause this physical change in the color of the hair of the Lord Jesus Christ?

The description of the Son of man (The Son, of man) is clearly symbolic. To imagine all the details literally would be grotesque (sword out of mouth, standing amidst the lampstands yet with huge hands grasping stars at vast distances from earth, feet ablaze). These are symbols which all have meaning, seen in prophetic vision but understood by intelligent faith (not imagined - and certainly not to be depicted - in superstition).

Are we to take the written description of the vision given by Christ Jesus via his angel to the Apostle John as literal?  Perhaps the clue is in the word "vision"?

@NigelJ, how do you know his hair is not as white as written in the Book of Revelation because Revelation is a mixture of literal and symbolic events. Take buying and selling for example, the buying and selling part of the beast system is literal so is the phrase referring to all walks of life rich, poor , small, great, master and slave to receive a mark

Two points might be worth considering here. First, the text itself, if read in full, gives a clearer understanding of what the Apostle John saw.

"And in the midst of the seven candlesticks one like unto the Son of
man, clothed with a garment down to the foot, and girt about the paps
with a golden girdle. His head and his hairs were white like wool, as
white as snow; and his eyes were as a flame of fire; And his feet like
unto fine brass, as if they burned in a furnace; and his voice as the
sound of many waters. And he had in his right hand seven stars: and
out of his mouth went a sharp two-edged sword: and his countenance was
as the sun shineth in his strength." Revelation 1:12-16 K.J.V.

If we take the colour of his hair to be literal, then (to be consistent) we must take the colour of his eyes to be literal (red/orange), as with the colour of his feet (copper-coloured). Further, if his whole countenance was as the sun for radiance and brightness, then what colour would that be? Or does that not indicate glory, and such awesome splendour that John fell as dead at his copper-coloured feet?
The Bible consistently uses mention of white hair to denote seniority, agedness, as in "the Ancient of Days" in other visions. So, if one decides the colour of Christ's hair in heaven is pure white, nobody need have a problem with that, given that he is uncreated, and from eternity - as ancient as ancient goes. But  consistency requires that he would also have red/orange eyes, and copper-coloured feet.
Second, given that the resurrected Christ was raised with a glorified body, yet no mention is made of the colour of his hair, one may speculate that his hair colour changed when ushered into the throne-room of God in heaven. And such speculation may give rise to a question such as this. But consider: Is the brightness of the glory of God any more than the brightness of the glory of the risen Lord in heaven - the Lord of glory? (So glorious that when he appeared on the road to Damascus, Saul was blinded, unable to see Christ in his risen glory. He saw "a light from heaven, brighter than the sun". See Acts 26:12-15 & 9:3-9.)
Think, too, of the awesome glory of the man, Jesus, when on the mount of transfiguration - "His face shone like the sun, and his clothes became as white as the light" (Matthew 17:2). No mention of the colour of his hair, because the emphasis is on his radiant glory. Besides, if his face was shining as the sun, that would make it impossible to see the colour of his hair. Who could look on such a face, what with his clothes also radiating phenomenal light? Surely the point of the description then was to show how, for a short time on Earth, the veiled glory of Jesus was unveiled? As for now, read this about Christ:

"The Son is the radiance of God's glory and the exact representation
of his being, sustaining all things by his powerful word." Hebrews 1:3
N.I.V. 1987 Ed.

This questions the question whether it was the brightness of the glory of God that 'caused' the risen Lord's hair to appear as white as snow. What about his own radiant glory? Just a different question! It would make for a good, fresh question, perhaps.

Maybe the presence of The Father came down upon him while he was on that mountain during the transfiguration?

I mean that wasn't the first time that God's presence came down on Jesus., even during the incident where a loud voice thundered and said this is my beloved Son with whom I am pleased with listen to him

When you said the mark of the beast is symbolic, I had to buy your view and try to see the Bible through your lens, the fact that no one can buy or sell lest he has the mark means there is a government entity that will require buyers and sellers to have that mark which means legislation by the antichrist which doesn't destroy the potential possibility of that mark being a tattoo of some sort

I am a software professional and its very easy to write a program that requires the selfie camera of a smartphone to scan your face for the numbers 666 or a camera fixed at a point of sale data capture that scans your hand for that, it will be literal and computers will enable it

@SoFewAgainstSoMany I note all your comments and that some are speculations, which are best left as that. What the Bible actually says, however, gives a basis for answers on this site; interpretations are a different matter, often giving rise to pointless debates or arguments, which this site clamps down on. I'm so old, I'm weary of ideas about literal marks of the beast being this, that, or the other. Every few years they change to the latest technology, then get replaced with the next one. So, I won't delve into that, if you don't mind.
